# number of possible positions/combinations that 4 squares within a frame can accommodate

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

If you have four squares that are contained within a frame and you are able to configure the squares in any number of rotations how many combinations are possible using four squares.

i.e. if you create an artwork that has four squares all painted differently within a frame how many variations of an artwork could you create by rotating the squares independently of each other (see picture).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are $4!$ ways to place the distinguishable images in the four corners, and for each corner there are $4$ orientations.  Hence $4! 4^4$.

Comment: apologies my lack of understanding do you mean 4x4 to the power of 4 that in my tiny mind world would be 64 combinations which doesn't seem enough.....i need a simple answer....sorry.

Comment: @MartinFreeman read more closely.  $4! = 4\times 3\times 2\times 1 = 24$ accounts for the orders in which the squares are placed (*assuming you are indeed allowed to swap the squares around*).  This amount is then multiplied by $4^4=4\times 4\times 4\times 4 = 256$ for a total of $4!\times 4^4 = 6144$... much higher than just $64$.  I'm not sure exactly what you did with your arithmetic, but $64$ is not even close.  I'm not convinced you know how to perform exponentiation correctly.

Comment: @MartinFreeman as for "*i need a simple answer*" This is as simple as it will get.  If you are going to be spending any amount of time with counting questions, you need to learn the fundamentals... including but not limited to the Rule of Product, the Rule of Sum, and common results such as what factorials and binomial coefficients are.  If you do not know what those are, then read a book.  If you still don't get it then that is what your question should be about.

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz I won't assume that you are any good at art ....I stumbled into this obviously elitist world of mathematicians to ask a simple question. I didn't realise part of the answer would be sarcasm.